# Laravel Eloquent how to get relationship self object?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I have tables with below relationship

[image: housing_advertisements->housing_ad_near_places->near_places]

And my HousingAdvertisement model has

```
public function nearPlaces()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HousingAdNearPlace::class);
}
```

and HousingAdNearPlace

```
public function nearPlace()
{
    return $this->hasOne(NearPlace::class, 'id');
}
```

when I make query like this:

```
HousingAdvertisement::with('nearPlaces.nearPlace')->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

I got HousingAdNearPlace object in HousingAdvertisement model:

```
[...
{
...,
"near_places": [
        {
            "id": 27,
            "housing_advertisement_id": 48,
            "near_place_id": 3,
            "created_at": "2021-06-29T12:23:35.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-29T12:23:35.000000Z",
            "near_place": null
        },
        {
            "id": 28,
            "housing_advertisement_id": 48,
            "near_place_id": 4,
            "created_at": "2021-06-29T12:23:35.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-29T12:23:35.000000Z",
            "near_place": null
        }
    ]
...]
```

How can I got self NearPlace model like this:

```
[...
{
...,
"near_places": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Park",
            "slug": "park",
            "created_at": "2021-06-29T06:25:57.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-29T06:25:57.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Beach",
            "slug": "beach",
            "created_at": "2021-06-29T06:25:57.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-29T06:25:57.000000Z"
        }
    ]
...]
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "Has Many Through" relationship on `HousingAdvertisement`

```
public function nearPlaces()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(NearPlace::class, HousingAdNearPlace::class);
}
```

And also define id keys as in ducumentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through-key-conventions

Answer (score 1):

You need to use laravel Model Accessor for generating `slug` from HousingAdvertisement's name row.

For that use -

```
public function slug()

    {
        return Str::lower($this->name);
    }
```

This will make a slug from name attribute. Add it on your `HousingAdvertisement` model. Now you need to cast it with query builder.

For that use -

```
protected $casts = [
    'slug' => 'string',
];
```

Add this on your `HousingAdvertisement` model. Finally you can query your database like -

```
HousingAdvertisement::find(auth()->user()->id)->get(['id', 'name', 'slug', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
```